# How can I display the google user's profile picture correctly in angular?

Tags: html, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase authentication and I have some data on the user, fx. the photoURL. When I try to display the image with that url, the image doesn't show up. But when I logged the url to the console and clicked the url, it opened the correct image. Why doesn't this code display the image?

```
<img class="align-self-start mr-5 img-thumbnail rounded-circle" src="{{user.photoUrl}}">
```

Comment: Certainly there is more than just that one line of code responsible for make this all happen.  Please edit the question to show the [complete, minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that anyone can use to reproduce the issue, especially the line of code that logs the URL that you expect to load into the image.

Comment: Can you try putting the image source without double qoutes ?

Comment: The issue was solved when instead of src="{{user.photoUrl}}" I used [src]="user.photoURL". I don't know why it makes a difference, I'm just glad it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

```
src="{{user.photoUrl}}"
```

use

```
[src]="user.photoURL"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is case error in your key value
It should be src=“{{user.PhotoURL}}”
Instead of src=“{{user.photo.Url}}”